# Order of evaluation for || and && in column formatting (JSON)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I'm having trouble finding an answer for how my JSON column formatting will be treated in SharePoint Online. Is there an order of operations/precedence based on the && (and) and || (or) operators, or is it simply read sequentially?

Take this statement, where I want to test the item to see if it has one of two acceptable Status levels as well as some value for Validation:

```
if([$Status]=='Pending' || [$Status] == 'Approved' && [$Validation]!='', 'inherit', 'none')
```

Is it treated as: if the Status is Pending and Validation is not null, or if the Status is Approved and Validation is not null, then inherit, else none. (This is what I want to test)

Or, is it treated as: if the Status is pending, or if the Status is Approved and the Validation is not null, then inherit, else none. (This wouldn't fit what I actually want to test)

If it is just read sequentially, then can I use brackets to force an order, like this?

```
if(([$Status]=='Pending' || [$Status] == 'Approved') && [$Validation]!='', 'inherit', 'none')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditions are simply read as sequentially.

First formula will be treated as:

If the Status is pending OR if the Status is Approved AND the Validation is not null, then inherit, else none.

You can use parentheses `()` to set the precedence. So, for your case you have to use the second formula in your question:

```
=if(([$Status] == 'Pending' || [$Status] == 'Approved') && [$Validation] != '', 'inherit', 'none')
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!